# Use different files (depend on Python) version for the Distutils installation?

Tags: python, distutils

I wrote my module in two versions, one for Python 2 (`module_py2.py`) and the other for Python 3 (`module_py3.py`).
I want Distutils can detect the Python version and install the right file.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean to write a `setup.py` that will install the correct version of the module when executed, or are you interested in interaction with pypi? In the first case is dead simple: the check `sys.version_info` in the `setup.py`.